# Apply an effect in slick slider react when there are no more images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slick.js

I'm new to react, and I'm trying to apply an effect when I do not have any more images in my carrousel. I am using react-slick, and although I was able to configure several things thanks to the documentation they have, but i can not apply this effect ...

What should happen is that once there are no more images in the carrousel, make a kind of "scroll" to the first image .. These images I'm getting from a get so I can have many images or few, I was investigating and I think I should have to do an if with a slickGoTo, but I honestly do not know how to get the values ​​to do it .. I appreciate any help!

here is my code:

```
function SampleNextArrow(props) {
  const { onClick } = props;
  return (
    <button type='button' onClick={onClick} className="slick-next slick-arrow" style={{ right: '0vw' }}><FaChevronRight size={'20px'} style={{ color: '#21849C', cursor: 'pointer' }} /></button>
  );
}

function SamplePrevArrow(props) {
  const { onClick } = props;
  return (
    <button type='button' onClick={onClick} className="slick-prev slick-arrow" style={{ left: '0vw' }}><FaChevronLeft size={'20px'} style={{ color: '#21849C', cursor: 'pointer' }} /></button>
  );
}
const settings = {
      initialSlide: 0,
      infinite: false,
      cssEase: 'linear',
      mobileFirst: true,
      nextArrow: <SampleNextArrow />,
      prevArrow: <SamplePrevArrow />,
      variableWidth: true,
      responsive: 
      [{
        breakpoint: 425,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2, slidesToScroll: 1, infinite: false
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 320,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1, slidesToScroll: 1, infinite: false
        }
      }]
    };



return (
              <div className='container'>
                <Slider {...settings} >
                  {
                    elementos.map((item, index) => { 
                        return (
                               <p>{item.name}</p>
                               <p>{item.subtitle}</p>
                            )
                    })
                  }  

                </Slider>
               </div>

)
```

Comment: If you just want to go back to the first slide you can set the slider as infinite. Check this link: https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/uneven-sets-infinite

Comment: thanks. Ali, I had already seen it, but it's not what I need ... that effect should be applied

Comment: I think you should write some codes in `beforeChange` and check if the current slide is the last one (according to number of slides), call a function and run your custom logic. Check this example which gets current and next slide number and does something: https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/slide-change-hooks